# VBA Activex button to activate specific keypress seq

Tags: excel, activex, vba

While Navigating my sheet I use the F5+[enter] to navigate back to the cell that I hyperlinked from on a different sheet in the same workbook.
I have now made an Activex button to act as a back button but I need the script to make it do an F5+[enter] when clicked on.

I have lots of hyperlinks from different areas that go to one specific sheet and I basically want the Activex button to return the cursor back from whence it came.

Any help would be appreciated
Thank you

*****Sorry My fault I meant Active X Button*****
Edited and re tagged. Much appreciated

Comment: My Mistake. See above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since application.goto function stores the last reference as default you can simply bind a key for the following command

```
    Application.Goto
```

This is not the perfect solution but it will do what you want. All you need to do is add this line to button_click.

Answer (score 0):

As a general note, mimicking the actions of the keyboard through VBA involves using the `Application.SendKeys` command. In your specific case, the code would be:

```
Application.SendKeys "{F5}"
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:01"))
Application.SendKeys "~" 'The tilde is the Enter key
```

Generally, I prefer *not* to use this methodology. On my computer, for example, the third line of code runs before the first line has completed its action. In that case, I'm sitting with the Go To dialog box on my screen. That's why I separate the two lines with a call for the system to delay processing.

EDIT: (I think I cut off part of my original post)

In my opinion, your best bet is to allow Excel to handle the flow back to the hyperlink cells. The also opens up the possibility to move back beyond just the last cell. Below is a loose example of the code, which should be adapted.

In a module, enter the below code:

```
Public strLastSheet(1 To 10) As Worksheet
Public strLastRange(1 To 10) As Range
Public nLastCell As Integer
Public nCurrentIndex As Integer


Sub SelectLastHyperlinkedCellFoShizzle()
    strLastSheet(nCurrentIndex).Activate
    strLastRange(nCurrentIndex).Select

     If nCurrentIndex <= 1 Then
         'Do Nothing
    Else
        nCurrentIndex = nCurrentIndex - 1
    End If

End Sub
```

In the ThisWorkbook  code, enter the following:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    nLastCell = 0
    nCurrentIndex = 0
End Sub
Private Sub Workbook_SheetFollowHyperlink(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Hyperlink)
    nLastCell = nLastCell + 1
    Set strLastSheet(nLastCell) = Sh
    Set strLastRange(nLastCell) = Target.Parent
    nCurrentIndex = nLastCell
End Sub
```

This is set to store the previous 10 hyperlink addresses. It should be further modified to disallow entries beyond 10 into the array, and perhaps shift the previous entries down the array.